# How to identify an edge or a corner of a parallelepiped at mouse click in a 3D space?

Tags: 3d, click, geometry, point

You could say that my problem is just like this guy's [How to get object in WebGL 3d space from a mouse click coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364693/how-to-get-object-in-webgl-3d-space-from-a-mouse-click-coordinate), but there are some differences that prevent me from applying those solutions.

Let's say I have an `java.awt.Canvas` that contains several 3D parallelepiped (??) objects. I want to implement `control points`. This means that when i click near an edge or a corner (inside or outside of the object, corner or edge selection mode), considering a level of tolerance, to draw a dot and retain its coordinates.

I am not interested in selecting the first object (so I would use ray/triangle intersections), i want to select the closest edge/corner to the mouse click position.

[image: It doesn't matter if I click inside or outside the object, the control point should be positioned on the edge]