# Unproject Webgl

Tags: matrix, graphics, camera, webgl

So I am trying to create a 2d drawing program in WebGL and I can draw everything fine but I am having a lot of difficulty detecting the location of mouse clicks.

I have a 4x4 projection matrix set up as follows:

```
mat4.perspective(45, this.gl.viewportWidth / this.gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, projectionMatrix);
```

I then have a 4x4 view matrix which holds the camera position as follows:

```
mat4.translate(viewMatrix, [camera.getX(), camera.getY(), camera.getZoom()]);
```

I can get a 2d vector of the position of the mouse click on the screen ranging from `[-1,-1]` in the top left to `[1,1]` in the bottom right.

What I want to be able to do is take the current position of the camera, get the frustum bounds on the z-plane and then use my relative mouse click positions to get the actual world space position on the z-plane.

Note:

- The camera does not rotate, only pan and zoom.
- Everything is drawn on the model matrix which is on the z=0 plane.

[image: see image here]

Comment: Then why do you use a perspective projection matrix at all? Anyway, have you looked at general unprojection? Basically, you want to multiply the mouse coordinates with the inverse view-projection matrix.

Comment: I want to use a projection matrix in order to zoom in and out. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes, use an orthographic projection matrix. But the unprojection procedure is the same for both (although you would need a reasonable depth for the perspective matrix).

Comment: Is something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583808/3d-math-screen-space-to-world-space/35590403#35590403 what you are looking for?

Comment: You might find [these articles useful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html). Panning and zooming can be thought of as just prepending a translation and scale matrix to your stack.